# Change div with multiple images on hover

Tags: html, css

I have div with multiple images that are static.

```
<div class="logos">
   <a href="#"><img src="img/logos/imgo.png"></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="img/logos/imgo1.png"></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="img/logos/imgo2.png"></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="img/logos/imgo3.png"></a>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is when I hover on some image to be changed with another image. How can be done this?
If it was just one image I know that I can make like this:

```
.logos:hover {
    background-image: url('img/logos/another-image.png');
}
```

but with multiple i don't know.

Comment: `.logos > img:hover`

Comment: If you are actually swapping out images you need javascript.

Comment: But how to tell different image for each href? Now they are 4 images. I want to show different image of each href

Comment: If I understand correctly, you will need to do this with javascript, specifically [mouseover event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp).

Comment: If you use each image as a bg image of the respective link you can use CSS.

Comment: No, not a big image of current image. The idea is that for every single image (logo) when is hovered will change current logo with another image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do this with jQuery

```
<div class="logos">
    <a href="#"><img data-hoverimg="img/logos/hoverimgo.png" src="img/logos/imgo.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img data-hoverimg="img/logos/hoverimgo1.png" src="img/logos/imgo1.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img data-hoverimg="img/logos/hoverimgo2.png" src="img/logos/imgo2.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img data-hoverimg="img/logos/hoverimgo3.png" src="img/logos/imgo3.png"></a>
</div>
```

and place the jQuery in ready function

```
jQuery('.logos img').hover(function(){
    var static_src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).data('hoverimg'));
    jQuery(this).data('hoverImg', static_src);
}, function(){
    var static_src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).data('hoverimg'));
    jQuery(this).data('hoverImg', static_src);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thank's for your answer. Just how exactly to place `jQuery in ready function`? I'm not very familiar with jQuery yet

Comment: I've added `$( document ).ready(function() { ...});` but doesn't seems to work. It didn't change the images.

Comment: What you see in browser console ?

Comment: Now I saw this in console - `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
localhost/:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: then you need to induce the jQuery.

Comment: Ok, now they are changed on hover but they didn't return when hover is removed. I mean when I point on image it is changed but when I move mouse from image didn't return original image. Can you help me with this?

Comment: but it is working fine here. Can you try removing cursor completely away from image. or make a fiddle of this and post a link here then i can help you.

Comment: Yes, on hover the image is changed but when I remove cursor of the mouse completely from the image it didn't remove the hovered image. This way I can change all images ... Let me try to make fiddle.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xf0xo7ok/ . You can see that when you remove mouse the image are staying.

Comment: you didn't change the code completely. there was still a hoverImg and I changed it to hoverimg now check http://jsfiddle.net/xf0xo7ok/1/

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank's for your help!

Comment: Just one last think - is it possible to add something to change a bit smoothly images? I've trying with something like `jQuery(this).animate("slow");` but doesn't seems to work

Comment: it won't work with the animate check the fiddle now http://jsfiddle.net/xf0xo7ok/6/

Comment: You mean that will be not possible to be like this example http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ANUT3/ ?

Comment: color can be animated but the source url that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could create ids for your imgs :

```
<a href="#"><img id="myimg1" src="img/logos/imgo.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img id="myimg2" src="img/logos/imgo1.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img id="myimg3" src="img/logos/imgo2.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img id="myimg4" src="img/logos/imgo3.png"></a>
```

And for the CSS :

```
#myimg1:hover {
background-image: url('img/logos/another-image1.png');
}
#myimg2:hover {
background-image: url('img/logos/another-image2.png');
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. How will be this `.logos img myimg1:hover { ... }`? Like this doesn't change it. If is only `#myimg1:hover { .. }` also didn't change any image.

Comment: Just dont use images. Use DIVs with a background image. Setting background-image on an image element is kinda strange.

Comment: You mean to make `<div id="logo"></div>` with background-image instead of images like now. And then on hover to change that background image with another?

Comment: @Doodlebunch is right., you should use `<div id="logo1"><a href="#"><img src="XX" /></a></div>` and so on ...

Comment: Sorry but I don't really get this. And on div logo1 will be background-image that will show on hover?

Comment: I would really discourage using id's as css selctors. Classes would work just fine here